# How to substitute psql script variables into strings in the query so it doesn't fail regardless if the variable is set or not

Tags: postgresql, variables, psql, postgresql-9.6, string-substitution

What I want is for the same query not to fail - regardless of the variable being set or not.
Then depending on the variable being set - returning relevant output.

Here's more or less what I mean/want:

```
--variable not set, returns not substituted string:
SELECT 'solution=:abc' result;
    result     
---------------
 solution=:abc
--variable set:
\set abc 5+7
SELECT 'solution=:abc' result;
    result     
---------------
 solution=5+7
```

**BUT INSTEAD** in both cases variable doesn't get substituted:

```
SELECT 'solution=:abc' result;
    result     
---------------
 solution=:abc
--variable set:
\set abc 5+7
SELECT 'solution=:abc' result;
    result     
---------------
 solution=:abc
```

I found that I need to use :'variable' syntax, so

```
SELECT 'solution=':'abc' result;
```

but this gives an extra (`'`) sign there:

```
    result     
---------------
 solution='5+7
```

and doesn't work when variable is not set

```
\unset abc
SELECT 'solution=':'abc' result;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT 'solution=':'abc' result;
```

What's going on?

Any way to make it work in both cases as described at the top?
I am on PostgreSQL 9.6.11

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: @fphilipe not really - It gives good explanation how this works but in essence I was looking for something that would work without raising an ERROR irrespective if the variable is set or not…

Answer (score 3):

psql's variable interpolation is syntax aware. If you want to use the variable

- verbatim, use `:abc`;
- as a string, use `:'abc'`;
- as an identifier (e.g. for a table name), use `:"abc"` (e.g. for a table name).

What you're trying to do is to combine two strings. Thus, syntactically the correct would be:

```sql
SELECT 'solution=' || :'abc' result;
```

The explanation as to why there's the extra quote when you do

```sql
SELECT 'solution=':'abc' result;
```

is that `:'abc'` gets replaced by `'5+7'`, resulting in

```sql
SELECT 'solution=''5+7' result;
```

The double single quote is how you escape a single quote in a string, thus the single quote in your output.

As to how to make the query work when there is no variable set, I think there you're out of luck. The only workaround would be to initialize the variable to the variable name itself:

```
db=# \set abc :abc
db=# SELECT 'solution=' || :'abc' result;
    result
---------------
 solution=:abc
```